# How to redirect sys.stdout to two or more separate widgets?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

```
class EmitStr(QObject):
    update_info_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.update_info_signal.emit(str(text))
        QApplication.processEvents()

sys.stdout = EmitStr()
sys.stdout.update_info_signal.connect(self.update_info)
```

I use this class to redirect stdout to textBroswer in a window. It works, but when I open the second window,  some problems come. For example, I have two windows, each of them have a textBroswer widget; I want these two windows run task separately by using QThread, like print 1 to 10, but all numbers printed will be displayed on the window opened later. How to solve this problem?

I want to solve this problem without by using module logging, don't change `print()`  in other `.py` files and other functions. I think `sys.stdout` is single; if I redirect `sys.stdout` to one window's `textBrowser`, it works, but when the second window opened, `sys.stdout` will be redirected to the second window and all the prints will be displayed on the second window. Here are two screenshots.

[image: open two windows before running]

[image: open the second window when the first window is running]

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: you mean i should provide some complete .py files that you can run it?

Comment: I add a picture of the application run.  1 to 10 should be displayed separately on the two textBroswer, but now displayed on the window opened later.

Comment: @zhangyida Please read the MRE link posted above, we need a code that we can copy, paste and run without any substantial modifications, and that code should be minimal (without anything that is not relevant to the problem) while **also** allowing us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Your question should remain strictly a question; but you are more than welcome to post an answer of your own. (The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77791421/revisions) contains all your edits.)

Comment: You deleted my description about screenshots, and now other users can't browser clear pictures by clicking links.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Firstly, introduce my project and express my needs again. My task is programming a pyqt5 project, it has a main window and ten sub-windows opened by clicking buttons in the main window. Each sub-window will run a task by using QThread. I want to display all the print() in .py files and redirect them to each textBrowser of sub-window. Generally, this need is easily satisfied by using module logging or pyqtSignal().emit(...). But I want to do this without replacing print() appeared in other .py files and functions.

Some ways I have tried and problems emerged. In the previous few days, I tried redirect sys.stdout by using code posted above, it runs fine when just one window is opened. But when I opened two sub-windows by clicking buttons in the main window, problems emerged. For example, each sub-window runs a task printing number 1 to 10, all the numbers printed will be displayed on the window opened laterly. I analysised the problem, maybe incorrect, welcome correcting me. I printed process id of sub-windows opened and there were the same. It looks like a pyqt5 project running in a process and all sub-windows opened just different threads contained by the process. And sys.stdout is a single resource in a process and it always be shared by all threads in the process. So, sys.stdout will be redirected to the window opened laterly and all the numbers will be displayed on the same window's textBrowser. I tried to use multiprocessing to open sub-window but failed, maybe it's available but I don't know how to do. So I changed my code posted above. Using module inspect to trace the function print() and get the sub-window's file name in order to redirect sys.stdout to the specific window's textBrowser. Here's the code.

```
class EmitStr(QObject):
    update_info_signal = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def write(self, text):
        # use module inspect to get caller file's name
        file_name = CommonUtils.get_file_name_by_stack(inspect.stack())
        self.update_info_signal.emit(file_name, str(text))
        QApplication.processEvents()
```

Firstly, I changed the update_info_signal's params. Before emitting string to the specific sub-window, I get caller file's name by using module inspect and then emit file's name and text together to the main window to update textBrowser. Here's the function code of updating textBrowser in the main window's class.

```
def update_info(self, file_name, info):
    window = self.get_window_by_name(file_name)
    cursor = window.ui.textBrowser.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(info)
    window.ui.textBrowser.setTextCursor(cursor)
    window.ui.textBrowser.ensureCursorVisible()
```

Here's the screenshot. [problem solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IML27.jpg)